# Using different MailServer for special Users in the same domain

Tags: email, gmail, synology

I'm new to this topic, so please have forbearance, if this is a dumb question.

At the Moment, we use GMail for all Mailaddresses. To save some money, the idea is, to use an own mailserver for the majority of the addresses, because they are only used for "inside-communication". So 100% Uptime is not important.

But we've got some Mailaddresses, that are more sensitiv. Like our Sales-Team or the Managers. Therefor i want to keep these accounts at Google.

So internal Mailserver for `personA@example.com` and `personB@example.com`. But the GoogleMailServer for `personC@example.com`.

Is this possible, without using a new Subdomain? I want to keep the existing addresses.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without subdomain - all mailboxes @example.com have to be on same server. You can define new MX records set in DNS for subdomain (ie. company.example.com) and point it to your mailserver. Mailboxes will then change to john@company.example.com instead of john@example.com. It will looks like this:

```
@ IN MX 10 first.gmail-server.com
@ IN MX 20 second.gmail-server.com
company IN MX 10 your.mailserver.com
```

Comment: `all mailboxes @example.com have to be on same server` . This is just flat-out wrong. Having a mail gateway that forwards incoming mails to different servers is quite easy. It's not necessary useful in this setup, but clearly possible.

Comment: Thank you! i was guessing, i need a subdomain. i also read, that it is possible to have more than one mailserver for a domain. Working as kind of fallback / load-balancing. But i hopped to choose the mailserver, depending on the receiver of the mail, like john@example.com -> MailServer_GMail and mike@example.com -> MailServer_Inhouse.

Comment: ok, mail gateway is way how to do it. But it has many not-so-good-sideeffects:

    1) You have to choose provider who has HA setup of gateways or manage HA setup of it by yourself
    2) Mail gateway is another point of failure, which is not necessary 
    3) i think when @ChrisJay have ability to run mail gateway with low risk, he can also run whole mailserver by himself and doesn't need to use gmail.

So my answer is maybe not perfect in all way, but it absolutelly OK in scope of question.